# Creating NPAPI plugin in Delphi and accessing exported APIs  using javascript

Tags: javascript, delphi, com, webgl

I have found a useful billards physics library in Borland delphi for my hobby project. The code is object oriented(in Object pascal). I want to visualize it using webGL (javascript) in chrome browser.

The idea is, I should have one call to make from the javascript which will access the interface from delphi lib and give me the new position, rotation and scale values in respective array.

For this I want to develop an NPAPI lib Scriptable plugin in Delphi(Meaning NO UI only lib of APIs).

1)I want to export those necessary physics APIs from the Delphi via this NPAPI plugin and access them in my html page using JavaScript. I am targeting chrome. 
2) Any simple "hello world" tutorial or article related to this will be highly helpful.

3)Any help on  using Firebreath to achieve the same is most preferable.
How to use Delphi with Firebreath?

Comment: Port it to JavaScript is a good option or use the new object pascal to JavaScript compiler

Comment: I was somehow optimistic that I could find a much straight forward solution. Becos, I had already found some success converting the delphi code to COM dll to use with C++ graphics. I just created an interface wrapper in IDL and directly called the function I required and the data structures passed as arguements to the function to retrive the result. I was expecting a similar approach. Is that impossible? Can you please suggest the best object pascal to javascript compiler.Its quite new to me.Note sure if you are suggesting something like this: http://op4js.optimalesystemer.no/about/ .

Comment: Why are you set on using Chrome and Javascript? What about a Delphi desktop app? Where I am leading with this is that if you want to make this public in a browser then you really need your code to be Javascript.

Comment: Yes thats the idea. Making it run in web browser.

Comment: I have setup the initial scene with the table,cue stick and balls. They are just waiting for that one call to the physics engine.

Comment: Where can i download that tool(op4js.optimalesystemer.no/about ). It seems that they ration the user limit for downloading the alpha version and that too is not available now. It would be great have that tool:)

Comment: If you don't have the physics in Javascript, how will you deploy it on people's machines. You can't deliver DLLs over the web very easily.

Comment: Firebreath doesnot support delphi? Sorry if that was a lame question. I have seen people develop C++ plugin lib for javascript to call using Firebreath.

Comment: You'll have to contact the developers but I trust you understand that it will cost money for op4js and that you'll almost certainly need to re-write some of the physics library to be compatible.

Comment: Host this library as scriptable Netscape plugin

Comment: Hi @user539484 thanks for the nice idea, I searched on the same and found some luck but the demos are most Ui based [link](https://www.mozdev.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8708). But I want my delphi part to be just a lib with out ui(I think that is what u rightly mentioned as scriptable plugin) . I want this lib to export functions that can be called from java script.Where can I find an hello world demo on NPAPI plugin that exports some functions to get called from javascript. That will be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- use a good HTML / JavaScript editor (for example the NetBeans IDE) create a basic HTML page which contains the "hard-coded" JavaScript to display the initial scene, and a HTML form to accept user input
- use Indy or Synapse to create a HTTP server (in Delphi), wich serves this HTML page and when the user submits form input, parse the form parameters and pass them to the billiard simulation, which should emit a list of graphic commands as a result - and convert these to WebGL (this is the hard part) statements
- from the HTTP server, send a response (HTML document) back to the client, with the JavaScript / WebGL statements embedded, so that the client will see the animation and the new playfield state
- repeat until end of game

Comment: Not sure that I want a total delphi based server solution. Infact I am trying to make in as much generic (non delphi) and closer to web and javascript. If there is no way I can use this delphi lib as such in a direct way I may look for converting it line by line to javascript. But it will be too tiring and boring. But javascript is must as I want it to be html5 way as I see it the future of cross platform application development.Its very unfortunate that an intelligence available  in hand is hard to use because I could not know the right technology to bind this language and platform barriers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a COM DLL and install it on the client's machine. Then Javascript can use its `ActiveXObject` class to access the COM object (or, under IE, you can use the `<object>` HTML tag). Make sure your COM object implements the `IDispatch` interface, as Javascript needs to use late binding since it is an interpretted environment and not compiled.