# NPAPI plugin framework Error

Tags: delphi, npapi, delphi-xe7, browser-plugin

I am trying to use NPAPI Framework from Yury Sidorov by following this answer:

[How to embed Delphi VCL form into HTML page using NPAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905660/how-to-embed-delphi-vcl-form-into-html-page-using-npapi/22905734?noredirect=1#comment46358638_22905734)

but I get an error with NPPlugin.pas. I am using delphi XE7 and here what i did by following Krom Stern instructions

```
procedure DefDebugOut(const Msg: string);
begin
  OutputDebugStringA(PAnsiChar(Msg + #13#10)); // Changed From Pchar To PAnsiChar
end;
```

but still getting error with compiler with this message

**[dcc32 Error] NPPlugin.pas(2215): E2010 Incompatible types: 'PWideChar' and 'PAnsiChar'**

Error raised on this procedure

```
procedure TPlugin.SetException(const msg: string);
var
  s: String;
begin
  try
    {$ifopt D+} NPP_DebugOut('Exception: ' + msg); {$endif}
    s:=UTF8Encode(msg);
    NPN_SetException(m_pScriptableObject, PAnsiChar(s));
  except
    { prevent any exception from leaking out of DLL }
  end;
end;
```

here is the procedure NPN_SetException

```
procedure NPN_SetException(npobj: PNPObject; msg: PNPUTF8);
begin
  NavigatorFuncs.SetException(npobj, msg);
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This NPAPI code was clearly designed for older versions of Delphi before the switch to Unicode in Delphi 2009.  The default `String`/`(P)Char` types are no longer aliases for `AnsiString`/`(P)AnsiChar`, they are now aliases for `UnicodeString`/`(P)WideChar`.  A `UnicodeString` cannot be casted to a `PAnsiChar`, just like an `AnsiString` could never be casted to a `PWideChar`.

In `DefDebugOut()`, the simplest fix is to change `PAnsiChar` to `PChar` and change `OutputDebugStringA()` to `OutputDebugString()`:

```
procedure DefDebugOut(const Msg: string);
begin
  OutputDebugString(PChar(Msg + #13#10));
end;
```

This is compatible with all Delphi versions (the code should have been doing this from the beginning - there was no reason to call `OutputDebugStringA()` directly).  `PChar` and `OutputDebugString()` map to `PAnsiChar` and `OutputDebugStringA()` in Delphi 2007 and earlier, and to `PWideChar` and `OutputDebugStringW()` in Delphi 2009 and later.  So everything matches.

In `TPlugin.SetException()`, `UTF8Encode()` returns a `UTF8String` in all versions of Delphi. However, prior to Delphi 2009, `UTF8String` was just an alias for `AnsiString` itself, but in Delphi 2009 it was changed to a true UTF-8 string type with full RTL support (it still has an `AnsiString` base, so it can still be casted to `PAnsiChar`).  When a `UTF8String` is assigned to a `UnicodeString`, the compiler performs an implicit data conversion from UTF-8 to UTF-16.  And as stated above, `UnicodeString` cannot be casted to `PAnsiChar`.  So you need to change the `s` variable from `String` to `UTF8String` for all Delphi versions:

```
procedure TPlugin.SetException(const msg: string);
var
  s: UTF8String;
begin
  try
    {$ifopt D+} NPP_DebugOut('Exception: ' + msg); {$endif}

    s:=UTF8Encode(msg);
    {
    UTF8Encode() is deprecated in Delphi 2009+.
    In those versions, you can use this instead:
    s := UTF8String(msg);
    }

    NPN_SetException(m_pScriptableObject, PAnsiChar(s));
  except
    { prevent any exception from leaking out of DLL }
  end;
end;
```

With that said, if you are still getting the same error on the `NPN_SetException()` call, then it means the second parameter of `NPN_SetException()` is declared as `PChar`. It needs to be declared as `PAnsiChar` instead.

Comment: True, but that wouldn't explain the compiler error that was reported. `DefDebugOut` compiles, although it is clearly wrong.

Comment: The edits are better, but you are still missing the root problem. My answer explains what that is. In short, `NPN_SetException` is declared incorrectly to accept `PChar`. That's the only explanation for the compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

I'll start with a piece by piece breakdown of what we can see. Bear in mind that we don't have `NPPlugin.pas` at hand and have to infer its contents from the information in the question. All the same, I think it's possible for us to do that accurately.

---

```
s := UTF8Encode(msg);
```

Here `s` is of type `string`. That's an alias for `UnicodeString`, encoded as UTF-16. So you convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8 and then back to UTF16.

You need it like this:

```
NPN_SetException(m_pScriptableObject, PAnsiChar(UTF8Encode(msg)));
```

Alternatively, if you need a variable to hold UTF-8 encoded text, declare it to be `UTF8String` which is `AnsiString(65001)`. If you changed the type of `s` to be `UTF8String` then the code in the question would be correct. Although somewhat more verbose than it would need to be.

---

Another problem is here:

```
OutputDebugStringA(PAnsiChar(Msg + #13#10));
```

Your cast doesn't make `Msg` actually be 8 bit encoded. However, you don't want to use the ANSI version of the function. You need this:

```
OutputDebugString(PChar(Msg + sLineBreak));
```

---

Your exception handler is misguided. It is the DLL's job not to leak exceptions. If you attempt to catch and suppress them all you will simply mask errors in your own code. You need to remove that exception handler and check for errors by following the instructions given by the library documentation.

---

Now to the bigger picture. None of the above explains your reported error. The only sound explanation for that is that your declaration for `NPN_SetException` accepts wide text. In which case you could make the code compile simply  by writing this:

```
NPN_SetException(m_pScriptableObject, PChar(msg));
```

Of course, that makes the appearance of UTF-8 somewhat inexplicable. In fact the library Mozilla does accept 8 bit text, UTF-8 encoded. So why would `NPN_SetException` expect to be passed UTF-16 text? Well it doesn't. The explanation is that you have declared `NPN_SetException` incorrectly. So, just to be clear, whilst `PChar(msg)` would make your code compile, it would not resolve your problem. You would be left with code that failed at runtime.

So, how did this happen? You've taken a working piece of code that used `PChar` aliased to `PAnsiChar` onto a Delphi with `PChar` aliased to `PWideChar` and not translated correctly. Even when you get your code to compile, it will not work correctly. You started with code like this:

```
function NPN_SetException(..., Msg: PChar): ...;
```

On older Delphi versions where `PChar` was `PAnsiChar` then this was correct. You are compiling this now on XE7 where `PChar` is `PWideChar` and so this is not correct. It needs to be:

```
function NPN_SetException(..., Msg: PAnsiChar): ...;
```

Then the calling code can be:

```
NPN_SetException(m_pScriptableObject, PAnsiChar(UTF8Encode(msg)));
```

---

My advice is that you:

1. Step back and revisit the handling of Unicode in Delphi.
2. Go back to you original code and change all the Mozilla interface code that uses `PChar` to `PAnsiChar`.
3. Whenever you need to provide `PAnsiChar` do it with `PAnsiChar(UTF8Encode(str))`.

Comment: [`NPN_SetException()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPN_SetException) accepts only UTF-8 as input.

Comment: @Remy Indeed. That's my point. Which is why the asker is wrong to declare the function as accepting `PWideChar`. That's the key point that you have not yet realised. That it is so can be seen from the error message.

Comment: https://www.mozdev.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=7590      here is the actual plugin

Comment: I don't think I need to see the plugin. I was able to diagnose the problem without it. I see you accepted Remy's answer even though I told him what the problem was, and he then edited that in with that final paragraph!! Perhaps my answer was badly written and I didn't get the message across clearly.